# How can I omit time at HTML {{ post.published_date }} tag?

Tags: python, django

How can I omit time at HTML `{{ post.published_date }}` tag?

I use Python and Django, I tried showing the published date, but I don't want to display time.

```html
<!--html file-->
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }} ... &nbsp {{ post.published_date }}</a>
```

e.g.

what I have:

> - This is post title ... Nov. 19, 2019  p.m. 5:37
> - This is post title, too! ... Nov. 24, 2019  a.m. 2:30

what I want:

> - This is post title ... nov. 19, 2019
> - This is post title, too! ... nov. 24, 2019

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that backticks (`\``) aren't used to emphasize things in Markdown, but to mark inline code and maybe filenames. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 8):

If you want only date in the template try this. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date) for more info

```
{{ post.published_date|date }}
```